# SSRS in Scale-Out deployment

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2014, azure-sql-reporting, azure-sql-server

Has anyone on this forum, deployed `SSRS` in Scale-Out deployment? Having 2 `SSRS` instances on different machines connect to one database?

I am trying to deploy 2 `SSRS` server loadbalanced to connect to one database which is hosted on `SQL-Always On` cluster.

However while configuring the reporting services, I do not find the 2nd server waiting to join the Scale-out deployment as mentioned in the Microsoft site -
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159114(v=sql.120).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it Myself - It seems like you need to have the different instance names to make the scale out deployment work. You cannot have all the servers in scaleout deployment use default instances which is what I was doing. I installed another named instance on one server and I was able to join it to  the scale-out deployment.